# Identify same commits (differen hash, but same content) in different branches?

Tags: git, github, hash, commit, pull-request

We planned to use three branches, PROD, UAT, DEV. The developer creates a branch for his change: CHG1. After development he pulls into DEV (PR#1: CHG1->DEV), then to UAT (PR#2: CHG1->UAT) after testing was done to PROD (PR#3: CHG1->PROD). But we seen an issue here. When the CHG2 is created from PROD, it will not contain PR#1 and PR#2. So, When creating the pull request PR#4, CHG2 to DEV it will list PR#3 and same for UAT. As the hash for PR#1, PR#2 and PR#3 are not the same.
So the question is, how can I ensure that those commits are the same?

```
PROD------------#3------
    |            |     |
UAT |--------#2--|-----|
    |        |   |     |
DEV |----#1--|---|-----|-----|#3+#4 << here git sees #3 is missing, so git wants to add it while it is the same as #1
    |    |   |   |     |     |
CHG1+----+---+---+     |     | 
                       |     |
CHG2                   |#3---|
```

[see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtQD5.png)

Comment: The commit tree is confusing. Instead of having lines for each branch, may you share what the tree looks like and show the commits every branch is pointing to?

Comment: What if you create `CHG2` based on `CHG1` or `DEV` instead of `PROD`?

Comment: @rodrigo - CHG1 is deleted after it merged. If I create from DEV, then the other two branch will have differences.

Comment: That CHG1 is deleted is not a problem, you can resurrect it as it is just the second parent of any of the PRs.

Comment: @rodrigo - many CHGx are going in paralell...

Comment: I see.... I assume that all CHGx are based on the same stable version. Why can't you just create the new fix based on that same stable version. Or if it is an improvement on one of these changes, say CHGn, then resurrect that branch and do the fix there? It is difficult to say without seeing the whole picture.

Answer (score 0):

In general, this workflow is going to create a lot of noise in your pull requests, because necessarily any commit that is in PROD buy not in DEV (including any merge commits) will show up in your pull request.  You may wish to adopt a different workflow for this reason.

However, assuming that you have merged the same branch (that is, exactly the same commits) into each branch and you always merge into DEV before PROD, you will have only extra merge commits in your branch, since GitHub uses a three-dot comparison and all of the common commits (that were in CHG1) should be in both branches.  If you see non-merge commits, then you have cause for concern.

Also, if you're trying to use squash merges in this case, you will only cause yourself sadness and none of this will work since squash merges don't preserve history.  Squash merges are extremely poorly suited for merging long-running branches into each other, so just don't do that.

Assuming you're merging exactly the same CHG1 branch into all three branches, you can also check that the second parent of each pull request is the same.  For example, you could run this command and they should print the same value:

```
$ git rev-parse PULL1^2 PULL2^2 PULL3^2
```

You'll need to replace `PULL1`, `PULL2`, and `PULL3` with the merge commits for the pull request.